# Two Django Apps using Same Database Table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

If I have two Django apps in the same project and both apps need to
use the same table in the same database, how should I describe this
table in two different models.py files?

Comment: It may make more sense to import the model from one app into the other app, and re-use the model (instead of reusing the database table).

Answer (score 3):

If you declare a table in two separate apps within the django project you will have two separate tables. What you want to do is declare the model in the app where it makes the most sense and then import the model from the second app.

For example:

`#app2.views`

```
from app1.models import MyModel
```

Like this you will be referencing the same table from both locations and you won't have any weird situation in which you look for data and you don't find it.